# Return location of first occurrence and return -1 if not found within the circular linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, circular-list

I am trying to assign -1 to the index if is not found within the circular linked list. This is the code I have currently:

```
public int indexOf(int value){
    Node temp = tail.next;
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    
    while(temp != null) {
        if(temp.value == value) {
            index = count;
            return index;
        }
        count++;
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    return index -1;
    
}
```

When I test the code these are the results:

The list should be [8 12 14]: [ 8 12 14]
*** TESTING INDEXOF ***
The index of 8 should be 0: 0
The index of 14 should be 2: 2

The code stops, it is supposed to print the index of 9, which is not in the list, which would be -1. I'm not sure how to fix this. My code just runs and doesn't produce any more results (well not in a time-efficient manner anyway).

Would I have to do :

```
while(temp == null){ 
index = -1;
break; 
  }
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: if its a circular list, your while loop will never end

Comment: You need some way of knowing when you've checked every element so you can stop and return -1. I would suggest keeping a reference to the first node you check and see if the current node is the same as the first node. Also you use `break` to immediately exit a loop even if the condition keeping the loop executing is still true. Your while loop at the very end of your question makes no sense. Since your list is circular, temp will never be null, and that loop could be just an if statement. `if(temp == null) index = -1;`

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure how to describe that in the code. I'm not too familiar with linked list. And I had an error that said something about null, so that's why I created the last while loop. But it didn't pertain to this specific method. Thank you fo your explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kaus in the comments pointed out your while loop will never end in the current state. Assuming that the `tail` actually points to the last element in your list the following code could be used:

```
public int indexOf(int value) {
    Node head = tail.next; //tail should be connected to a head
    Node current = head;
    int index = 0;
    do {
        if (current.value == value) {
            return index;
        }
        current = current.next;
        ++index;
    } while (current != head);
    return -1;
}
```

As it goes through all elements (starting from the head) and ends if it encounters head again (assuming that the searching value is not found).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!